# IF Condition Within Sum in JOOQ

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

MySQL allows me to run the following query:

```sql
SELECT SUM(IF(COLUMN1 > COLUMN2, COLUMN2, COLUMN1)), SUM(IF(COLUMN3 = 0,4 ,10)) FROM TABLE;
```

How can I do this in `JOOQ`?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're referring to MySQL's [`IF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function, which is currently not supported by jOOQ, simply because `if` is a reserved keyword in Java, so there's no 1:1 mapping to a Java method for this function.

But as you can also see in MySQL's documentation, you can very easily rewrite `IF()` to the more standard `CASE` expression. So, your query would be this one in SQL:

```sql
SELECT 
  SUM (CASE WHEN COLUMN1 > COLUMN2 THEN COLUMN2 ELSE COLUMN1 END), 
  SUM (CASE WHEN COLUMN3 = 0 THEN 4 ELSE 10 END)
FROM TABLE
```

Which translates to jOOQ as follows:

```java
using(configuration)
  .select(sum(when(TABLE.COLUMN1.gt(TABLE.COLUMN2), TABLE.COLUMN2)
             .otherwise(TABLE.COLUMN1)),
          sum(when(TABLE.COLUMN3.eq(0), 4).otherwise(10)))
  .from(TABLE)
  .fetch();
```

[See the jOOQ manual's section about the `CASE` expression for details](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/case-expressions/).

As always, this static import is implied:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```